# Conditional AddWithValue as one-liner

Tags: c#, vb.net, sqlclient

I'm looking for a simple one-liner to accomplish the following in the SqlClient namespace, to save typing out all the if-else statements. Assuming:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("MyStoredProcName", MySqlConnection)
```

This is what I'm trying to one-line:

```
If MyDataSet.Tables("MyTableName").Columns.Contains("MyColumnName") Then
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SQLParameter", True)
Else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SQLParameter", False)
End If
```

Anyone have anything clever and readable? C# fine too.

EDIT: n8wrl's answer does what I asked for, but I should have been more clear: I am looking for the more generic ability to add any data type to the SQLparameter. i.e. Instead of "True or "False" it could be StringA and StringB.

```
If MyDataSet.Tables("MyTableName").Columns.Contains("MyColumnName") Then
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SQLParameter", "StringA")
Else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SQLParameter", "StringB")
End If
```

Comment: Although this could be condensed down to one line, I think it's more readable the way it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SQLParameter", MyDataSet.Tables("MyTableName").Columns.Contains("MyColumnName"))
```

You might want to consider the fact that the original version might be more readable.

**UPDATE:**

If you need to have values that are not boolean, you can use the [`IIf` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx) like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SQLParameter", IIf(MyDataSet.Tables("MyTableName").Columns.Contains("MyColumnName"), "StringA", "StringB"))
```

Comment: I agree. Someone could wonder if you're deliberately passing the existence of column as a parameter. Or you could add a comment like "True if column exists else false."

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SQLParameter", MyDataSet.Tables("MyTableName").Columns.Contains("MyColumnName"))
```